# Starting OpenSSH server in Windows with debug messages enabled (-d)

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, openssh

I have a very strange problem trying to make the `OpenSSH server` that ships with Windows 10 working fine. Basically, if I start the service manually by running `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd.exe`, everything works fine, but when I start the service through the Windows GUI or `Start-service sshd` from Powershell, I am not able to connect (I get a publickey denied - I have disabled password logging in the configuration file, so the problem might be a permission issue when trying to read the `authorized_keys` file). I would like to understand better what is going on by reading the debug messages of the `sshd` daemon, i.e. what you get by starting manually with `-d`, but even if I add the `-d` option to the Windows GUI which allows to specify startup parameters for a service, I am not sure where I should be reading those messages (i.e. the event viewer does not contain those messages). It would be good if there was a way to add startup parameters to the `Start-service sshd` powershell command and read those messages in the Powershell session... Any idea?

Comment: @Ramhound : no, it's debug, as per man page:

-d' Debug mode. The server sends verbose debug output to the system log, and does not put itself in the background. The server also will not fork and will only process one connection. This option is only intended for debugging for the server. Multiple -d options increase the debugging level. Maximum is 3.

Anyway, let's focus on the problem, thanks

Comment: [`sshd -E`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#E) – Can you use this option?

Comment: I tried but it does not seem to have any effect as the log is not created as the file I specify after the - E option

Answer (score 16):

The Windows OpenSSH server logs to the event log by default. You should look in the Event Log Viewer under Applications and Services Logs -> OpenSSH. The Admin log shows errors, the Operational log shows Informational messages.

The OpenSSH logging is controlled by your `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config` file. The entry `SyslogFacility` determines the log location.

I got the answer from here: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Logging-Facilities.

The event log may miss some extra lines that would otherwise be shown in a log file (e.g. the reason why `authorized_keys` is ignored). To see them, edit `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config` (e.g. with notepad.exe run as an administrator), then set:

```
SyslogFacility LOCAL0
LogLevel Debug3
```

Restart the OpenSSH SSH Server service and expect logs to appear in `C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs\sshd.log`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still trying to solve the specific underlying problem described in the question (SSHD works fine when I start it, but not when started as a service), just make sure that the service is logging in as your account instead of Local System.

1. Open "Services".
2. Right click sshd -> Properties.
3. Go to the "Log On" tab and click "This account" -> Browse...
4. Type your username in the text box and click "Check Names". You may have to click "Advanced..." and find it there.
5. Once the account's configured correctly, right click sshd and restart the service.