# SSH into a passwordless windows 10 pc

Tags: ssh

I installed OpenSSH server in a virtual machine with no password for the user and whenever I try to SSH into it, I am asked for a password; since this is a virtual machine that will be scrapped, I don't want to go into key authentication.

- `%ProgramData%\ssh\sshd_config`: I tried changing `PasswordAuthentication` and  `PermitEmptyPasswords` but it didn't work:

  ```ini
  AuthorizedKeysFile      = .ssh/authorized_keys

  PasswordAuthentication  = no
  PermitEmptyPasswords    = yes

  Subsystem  sftp         = sftp-server.exe

  Match Group             = administrators
  AuthorizedKeysFile      = __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
  ```

Comment: Provide the entire configuration file for the OpenSSH server by editing your question

Comment: @Ramhound Done!

Comment: You have simultaneously disallowed `PasswordAuthentication` and allowed empty passwords leaving you no authentication since `PubkeyAuthentication` is commented out. The verbose logs from the server would also be helpful.

Comment: Even when I set `PasswordAuthentication  on` and `PermitEmptyPasswords yes` it still does not work, also how do i get the verbose logs?

Comment: After you uncommented `PasswordAuthentication` and set it to `on` you rebooted the OpenSSH Server service? [How you view the OpenSSH server logs is well documented.](https://superuser.com/questions/1635361/starting-openssh-server-in-windows-with-debug-messages-enabled-d).  What we need in order to diagnose your problem is what the sever is believes the problem is. If you do provide a password to the specified Window's user are you able to connect to the server?

Comment: yes i did and restarted the vm too..just to be sure.

Comment: Please provide the minimum amount of information that the server is providing for the user's authentication error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133124/discussion-between-ramhound-and-awesomevk47).

Comment: Yes after adding password to my vm it works fine.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler and more efficient to use an RSA key and copy the public key into `%ProgramData%\ssh\authorized_keys` _(IIRC, that's the key file for `Administrators`)_,?

Comment: @DanielB - In some cases there are default values and unless changed the default will be used.  However, I question if the correct configuration file is being modified, and the author has not provided the necessary information to further diagnose their server

Comment: @DanielB Equal signs are [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Keys_(properties)) for ini files _([either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Name/value_delimiter) is valid)_, including OpenSSH configs - I added the equal signs when I edited the question, else it won't syntax highlight for ini. _([examples](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH): [Windows](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH/Windows/sshd_config) | [Linux](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH/BSD-Linux/sshd_config))_

Comment: `sshd_config` is *not* an INI file. Its format is clearly described in the man page and equals signs aren't part of it. I suggest you not alter a question like that.

Comment: Everybody I did not put any "equal signs" somebody edited my post idk:((

Comment: @JW0914 I cannot find the "authorized_key" folder in server machine

Comment: @DanielB It's stated specifically in the header of the man page for `ssh_config` and assume it was an oversight for the `sshd_config` since both use the same formatting [server: `sshd_config` | client: `ssh_config`]: "_Configuration options may be separated by whitespace or optional whitespace and exactly one `=`_". The `sshd_config` man page states `NAME=VALUE` is valid, so I'm assuming an oversight is why it's not in the header of the `sshd_config` man page _(it's how all my `sshd_config` are formatted)_. Such modifications wouldn't be necessary if site syntax highlighting worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy the client's public key into the server's authorized_keys file.
2. Disable the last AuthorizedKeysFile line like the below example.
3. Restart the sshd service (Restart-Service sshd).

   ```
   AuthorizedKeysFile      = .ssh/authorized_keys

   PasswordAuthentication  = no
   PermitEmptyPasswords    = yes

   Subsystem  sftp         = sftp-server.exe

   Match Group             = administrators
   #AuthorizedKeysFile      = __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
   ```