# SFTP account unable to log in the disconnect network drive on Windows server

Tags: networking, openssh, sftp, sshd

We migrated the method for transferring files from any sources from FileZilla Server (Port 21) to SFTP Server (Port 22) due to security policy. FTP account with port 21 can log in to the folder located on the disconnected network drive.

I have set up SFTP server in Windows server already using OpenSSH by the following steps.

Drive C is a normal drive and Drive F is a disconnected network drive.

1. Install OpenSSH via Powershell
2. Configure 'sshd_config' from C:/ProgramData/ssh

```
#override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    internal-sftp

Match Group "SFTP Users"
    ChrootDirectory C:/FTP
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

3. Create a new user and add to 'SFTP Users' Group via Computer Management(Local).
4. Add "SFTP Users" group to the folder C:/FTP and F:FTP for setting permission/policy via Properties-Security of the folder.

SFTP users can log in to the folder C:FTP, then we change the config of sshd from

ChrootDirectory C:/FTP   ---> ChrootDirectory F:/FTP and restart OpenSSH service.

But SFTP users cannot reach out to drive F:FTP.

[image: FileZilla]

Is there any configuration that I can change to fix this without intervening in the property of the disconnected network drive?

Comment: Does the folder on F:\ exist? Did you check the permissions on it? Did you make sure that the new configuration is being loaded?

Comment: Sure, there is the existing folder on the drive along with the granted permission but still, it doesn't work.

Comment: What messages are shown in the [eventlog](https://superuser.com/questions/1635361/starting-openssh-server-in-windows-with-debug-messages-enabled-d)?