# setting up ssh between two windows machines - permission denied

Tags: windows, ssh, permissions, openssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to establish ssh connection between two Windows machines. Here are things I did:

- I installed OpenSSH on both machines, generated the ssh keys and placed the public key on the host machine in the `authorized_keys` file in `.ssh` folder and kept the public and private key files in my local machine in the `.ssh` folder.
- The sshd and ssh-agent are in the Running state, the sshd_config file has set `"PubkeyAuthentication yes"` and `"PasswordAuthentication no"`.
- To make sure it is not a firewall issue I created a rule to allow inbound traffic on port 22.
- I disabled inheritance in the file permissions. In file permissions for `authorized_keys` there is only my user and it has Full control.
- Also I commented the line below in `sshd_config`:

```
# Match Group administrators                                                    
#       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

Another thing I noticed is that when I do `Stop-Service sshd` and run `sshd` on host then I am able to successfully ssh into host, however when I do `Start-Service sshd` then there is Permission denied issue. What is the difference here?

What could be the reason here for the Permission denied? What I am missing?

The context (not sure if important): I am having a stationary computer and a laptop, I am trying to set up the ssh so I can access the stationary computer from my laptop remotely.

Edit:
I found out here: [Starting OpenSSH server in Windows with debug messages enabled (-d)](https://superuser.com/questions/1635361/starting-openssh-server-in-windows-with-debug-messages-enabled-d) that I should change the Log On property, however after successfully changing it to my user I am getting the `Could not start the openssh ssh server service on local computer, error 1069: the service did not start due to logon failure`, despite password being accepted as correct.
In the logs I can see that the correct key is being attempted but fails:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:r4hP8m3JFxP+ZM4njv+t/r2LajUx36I6Si5yNoVLtI agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/1156050/1044055).

Comment: Post the server logs as the service is started and the user attempts to login. Post the client logs also, and the entire server configuration

Comment: I added what is displayed in client logs, in the server logs in the Event Viewer I can't see any logs.